# My Python Caeser Cipher program stops shifting after 30

Tags: python, encryption

I created a function to split inputed string into list of words and then replace the letters in each word with its shifted counterpart but when I set the shift to over 30 it prints unchanged.

```
def ceaser_cipher_encoder(string , num):
        alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m",
                    "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

        new_string = ""
        string_list = string.split(" ")
        new_list = []
        for word in string_list:
                word1 = ""
                for charecter in word:
                        letter_position = alphabet.index(charecter)
                        letter_position_with_shift = letter_position + num
                        if letter_position_with_shift > 25:
                                letter_position_with_shift = 0 + ((letter_position - 25) - 1)
                        word1 += charecter.replace(charecter, alphabet[letter_position_with_shift])

                new_list.append(word1)
                end_string = " ".join(new_list)



        return end_string




message = ceaser_cipher_encoder("hello dad", 35)
print(message)
```

Comment: Why not just use the modulus operator (`%`)? (e.g. `(letter_position + num) % 26`)

Comment: The key space or shift itself is based on the alphabet size. You cannot perform a shift over the size of the alphabet. The modulus operation will allow you to do so, but doing so means still that you are extending the to allow for equivalent keys.

Comment: This is important if you go on to study cryptography deeper, as you need to stay inside of the groups that are defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One useful trick here is to use the **modulus** operator (`%`). It will take care of the shift for you.

Here is how I would do :

```
def ceaser_cipher_encoder(string , num):
        alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m",
                    "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

        new_string = ""
        for c in string:
                new_string += alphabet[(alphabet.index(c) + num) % len(alphabet)]
        return new_string
```

Let's say `c` is "y" and `num` is 10. You would then have `alphabet.index(c)` equal to 24, so the shift would return 34. Since 34 modulo 26 is 8, it would append `alphabet[8]` ("i") to `new_string`.

I used `len(alphabet)` instead of hard-coding 26 so that you can change your alphabet and the code would still work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your if statement:

```
if letter_position_with_shift > 25:
    letter_position_with_shift = 0 + ((letter_position - 25) - 1)
```

should really be:

```
if letter_position_with_shift > 25:
    letter_position_with_shift = 0 + ((letter_position_with_shift - 25) - 1)
```

That being said, it would be better to use the [modolo operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-a-modulo-operator-in-python/) instead of an if statement here, to handle any multiple of 26, not just 26-52. Think about the case where num = 100, for example.

Try changing your for loop body to:

```
letter_position = alphabet.index(charecter)
letter_position_with_shift = (letter_position + num) % 26
word1 += charecter.replace(charecter, alphabet[letter_position_with_shift])
```

I would also suggest replacing the last line with:

```
word1 += alphabet[letter_position_with_shift]
```

Because you are appending that letter to `word1` anyway, you don't really need to call replace on a character to get alphabet[letter_position_with_shift]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your code a bit shorter, then you can try this:

```
def cipher(plain: str, offset: int) -> str:
    abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    return plain.translate(str.maketrans({c: abc[(idx + offset) % len(abc)] for idx, c in enumerate(abc)}))

print(cipher("hello dad", 35))  # Output: qnuux mjm
```

Further reading:

- [dict comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/dict_comprehension.html)
- [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)
- [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)
- [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)